# Accessing a hasMany Association in a Sencha Touch 2 list tap handler programmatically

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

I am new to ST2, and I am having difficulty with trying to do something I think should be simple.

I have a model that is a user with a hasMany association called emails. I have a list that successfully loads the top level user items, and when I tap on an item in the list, I am able to access the users properties using the record passed into the tap event via

```
record.get('displayName');
```

But any way I have tried to access the collection of emails from the record object has not worked.

I've tried :

```
record.get('emails'); // doesn't work 
record.getEmails(); // doesn't work 
record.emails().each(...);
```

`record.emails()` exists, but no idea what it is. each() yields nothing, though it evaluates ok.

Can anyone explain to me how to get at the association data elements from this record object?

Here is an example of the JSON I am generating :

```
[
   {
      "id":0,
      "displayName":"Display Name 0",
      "emails":[
         {
            "value":"email@thehost.us",
            "type":"home",
            "pref":"true"
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`record.emails()` is the correct way to do it. That will return an instance of `Ext.data.Store` which you can then load (if there is no data) the records, or loop through them.

More documentation on the hasMany association is available here: http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.data.association.HasMany

Comment: Thanks very much for the response. When I access `record.emails()` it is always empty, whether I call `load()` or not on it. I put an onload handler on the store, and in the raw data there I see the emails array, but somehow it is lost by the time I access it within my list tap handler from the store record I am passed there. Any advise on how I might figure out how it is getting lost? Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what went wrong, I rebuilt everything from the ground up and the 'emails()' was working.